# Difficulty getting Python 3.3 and numpy to work

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, numpy, python-2.5

I'm newer to python, but have seem to screwed things up trying out the new python.

I have an older mac which runs python 2.5 as it's default. I've installed python 3.3. However, when I upgraded numpy my python 2.5 now gives me the:

Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
        its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
        your python intepreter from there.

regardless of the directory I run python from. And python 3.3 can't find the numpy module. Did I miss something? How can I get 2.5 running numpy again and get python 3.3 to find the module?
I also can't get virtualenv to work as it gives me the error that the script needs python2.6, even after I installed virtualenv-2.5 and can't get the python=python3.3 to do anything either. I seem to have tried everything I can find. I'm afraid I've installed too much and have some hidden conflict.
Thanks

Comment: How did you upgrade numpy?

Comment: Perhaps take a look at Continuum's Anaconda distribution which packages python3 and numpy: http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkgs.html

Comment: OK. Figured it out. Rookie mistake.
Yes I upgraded numpy and pretty much everything else I could but that didn't fix it. 
I wasn't paying enough attention to the operating system. I had been using a newer macbook pro with 10.7 and now am on a older pro with 10.5. The newer numpy, and python versions I downloaded were for 10.6 or newer. Once I downloaded the version 2.7 that fixed it all.
Moral to the story, make sure you know about the mac you're using.
Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 1):

download numpy from this site : http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

In case you want to check the version of numpy on your system , write this following code on your IDE :

```
import numpy
numpy.version.version
```

Hope this would help !